# Can't link to specific OpenSSL library (Linux Mint 13)

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, openssl

OpenSSL doesn't work well with valgrind unless you build it with a particular option so I've build OpenSSL again so that I can debug a program easily. The problem is, every time I build the program it links to an OpenSSL library I do not want. My makefile prints out a lot but the two lines that are most important are:

```
cc /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 -L/opt/local/lib  -shared  -o bin/libcbitcoin-crypto.2.0.so build/CBOpenSSLCrypto.o
cc build/testCBNodeFull.o -L/home/matt/Desktop/cbitcoin/bin -lcbitcoin.2.0 -lcbitcoin-network.2.0 -lcbitcoin-storage.2.0 -lcbitcoin-threads.2.0 -lcbitcoin-logging.2.0 -lcbitcoin-crypto.2.0 -lcbitcoin.2.0 -lcbitcoin-file-ec.2.0 -lcbitcoin-rand.2.0 -L/opt/local/lib -lpthread -levent_core -levent_pthreads /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -o bin/testCBNodeFull
```

As suggested elsewhere I'm specifying the precise location of the OpenSSL library I want. However `ldd bin/testCBNodeFull` gives me this:

```
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

There is apparently nothing wrong with the library I want to link to:

```
$ file bin/testCBNodeFull
bin/testCBNodeFull: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xd9472ecc11e12dc66d165c807a5dbe31fd461cf2, not stripped
$ file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xb75602dc478ae55576e21aac5251b915b1653e73, not stripped
```

Both compiled as x86-64 as you can see. Maybe there is a tool that allows me to change the location of the shared library of the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared libraries are loaded at *runtime*, not compile time. So, you need to tell valgrind which OpenSSL library you want it to use at runtime. You can do this by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the directory containing your rebuilt object.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/matt/mylib
#now try ldd bin/testCBNodeFull
```

Comment: Thanks, this works... Except OpenSSL is still giving valgrind errors despite me using -DPURIFY. :-(